# Can't receive the TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED event in Android 9.0

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

In Android 9.0 devices, my accessibility service has connected, but can't received `TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED` event, the other event such as `TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED` can be received.

Otherwise, it can be received in Android 8.0 devices.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:packageNames="com.tencent.mm"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity" />
```

```java
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "received event： " + event);
        int eventType = event.getEventType();
        switch (eventType) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
                handleNotification(event);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question.
In Android 9.0, the android system has some modification in `TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED` event （Specific changes unknown）, so can't received the event. The solution way is deleting `android:packageNames="com.tencent.mm"`in accessibility config xml, and filter the package in your accessibility service. In this way, the `TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED` can be received in Android 9.0.
There is another way to solve this problem by using NotificationListenerService instead of AccessibilityService in Android 9.0.

Comment: Is it possible to differentiate between the creation of a notification and clearing it?